# On start Windows Service throws Event ID ( 5000 ) in Source ( .NET Runtime 4.0 Error Reporting ) error

Tags: windows, windows-services

I have come across an issue and needed to know if anyone has faced it. I have written a c# windows service which calls a web service (asmx) to perform some function.
The service seems to be working fine when deployed on the local machine. But the moment its deployed and run in a remote development testing environment (Win server 2003), it throws an error captured as event log below.

"
The description for Event ID ( 5000 ) in Source ( .NET Runtime 4.0 Error Reporting ) cannot be found. The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display messages from a remote computer. You may be able to use the /AUXSOURCE= flag to retrieve this description; see Help and Support for details. The following information is part of the event: clr20r3, yllddkcpf0zkiftk0gcwtfigwkqck35d, 1.0.0.0, 50069cd9, tpplc.intranet.applications.incidentreporting.emailingservice, 1.0.0.0, 50069cd9, d, 18a, system.nullreferenceexception, NIL.
"

The following is the stripped but relevant version of the code snippet.

The Onstart of the service –

```
      protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
      {

      try

       {           
         //Some initialization code
            …
            …

        //Start the thread to notify email recipients.
            emailThread = new Thread(NotifyRecipients);
            emailThread.Start();
        }
 }


 private void NotifyRecipients()

 {          
 //Now call the web service to fetch the execution time which is actually set from the web app.


       GetEmailSchedule();           

        while (true)
        {                
            // Some Logic               

            //Send email only on the scheduled time of the day AND if the current time matches the 
            //email scheduled time OR if the current hour is greater than the scheduled hour.
            if ((DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay >= executionTime) && (!EmailSent))
            {
                SendMail();// In this method call Email is sent and the EmailSent flag is set to true.
            }
        }
    }

    private void GetEmailSchedule()

     {            
      try
          {                
            LogModule.LogDebug("Calling WebMethod instance to get Email Schedule");

            EmailService.IncidentDetails emailSchedule = new EmailService.IncidentDetails();// Place of error

            emailSchedule.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            LogModule.LogDebug("Calling WebMethod to get Email Schedule");
            string schedule = emailSchedule.GetEmailSchedule();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(schedule.Trim()))
            {
                //Get the default time from the app.config file to send emails to recipients.

            }
            else
            {
                //Get the individual time components
                string[] scheduleSplit = schedule.Split(',');
                executionHour = Convert.ToInt32(scheduleSplit[0].Trim());
                executionMinute = Convert.ToInt32(scheduleSplit[1].Trim());
            }

            executionTime = new TimeSpan(executionHour, executionMinute, 0);


            //Check if the retrieved exeuction hour or minute has changed from its last execution so that
            //emailsent flag can be reset and email can be sent in the new schedule again.
            if (executionHour != ExecutedHour || executionMinute != ExecutedMinute)
            {
                EmailSent = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogModule.LogError("Error Occurred: " + ex.Message + " ; Inner Exception: " + ex.InnerException.ToString());
            LogEvent("Error Occurred: " + ex.Message + " ; Inner Exception: " + ex.InnerException.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
            SendExceptionMail(ex);
        }
    }
```

Upon debugging by adding custom logs, I realized this happens the moment the web service is instantiated to call the web method in the GetEmailSchedule() method which is 
EmailService.IncidentDetails emailSchedule = new EmailService.IncidentDetails();

Not sure why it happens. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It does not look to be a problem with your web service. Post the code that logs the events, within the LogEvent method. This error is due to logging the event in an unavailable Log Source.